# Lolcode puzzle in level 9

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm stuck on the following. Is there a more effective way to delete the code block besides what I've been doing which is "d4j" from the top line?

[image: lolcode puzzle]

Comment: what are the keyboard layout you have available? I don't think I have the keyboard combination to replace more than 1 letter at a time...

Answer (score 5):

Turns out "d4j" was the absolute minimum number of keystrokes required to delete the block, according to a Facebook comment by the game's creator,

> "There are 5 areas to fix in this text. Delete the first with two
>   keystrokes, change the case of the second with one keystroke, move one
>   line down and change the next area with 2 keystrokes. Move to the next
>   area with 2, delete with another 3, get to the last with another 2,
>   and change them with another 3."

For anyone that's curious, where I messed up was using "RI" on the second block instead of just "~"

Comment: It took me a long time to realize I could `3x` instead of `d3l`.

Comment: what are the keyboard layout you have available? I don't think I have the keyboard combination to replace more than 1 letter at a time...

Comment: For me, 5dd also worked

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

- j    Move to W
- fC   Store move to CK
- k    Move up to reset counter
- j    Move to W
- 3x   Delete WAI
- ~    Change case of I
- j    Move to N
- 5~   Change case of n has
- 5j0  Move to start of PLZ OPEN
- d4j  Delete 4 lines
- ;    Move to CK
- 2rG  Replace CK with GG
- 20b  Move to new found key

Comment: what are the keyboard layout you have available? I don't think I have the keyboard combination to replace more than 1 letter at a time...

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. I am short of 1 key every time.